# How to hide a SharePoint list column if its own value is empty?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, conditional, formula, hide

Is there a way with SharePoint online lists, to hide a column if the user did not fill in a value for it?  If so, how can I setup this conditional logic for the column to check against itself?

I have 20 non-required fields a user can fill in. But if they only choose to fill in 5 of the 20, I want to hide the other 15 whenever we are not in edit mode.

Comment: Are you using modern UI? Have you considered customizing your for with Power Apps?

Comment: Yes I am using the modern UI and yes I am ready to dive in to Power Apps if this is what it naturally leads me to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Please the following steps:**

Step1: Select an item in the list to open the "**Edit Form**" panel

Step2: On the "**Edit Form**" panel, click on "**Edit columns**" link

[image]

Step3: On the "**Edit columns in the form**" panel, select column and click "**Edit conditional formula**"

[image]

Step4: On the "**Edit conditional formula for xxx field:**" panel, type the following formula:

```
=if([$xxx]=='','false', 'true')
```

[image]

Step5: **Save** it and you will notice that it becomes grayed out.

[image]

Step6: And so on, repeat the Step3 and Step4

Step7: The “**Edit Form**” panel will hide empty fields.

[image]

Comment: Will it show the columns when in new/edit mode?

Comment: Good point. no, it won't show a column in the New/Edit mode.

Comment: This works perfectly thank you. The one thing I noted was how important it was to make sure you get the "field name" of the columns, to set in your conditional statements.  Sometimes depending on the column name displayed out in the open is not correct.